# On Hover image expands on top of other images on page

Tags: html, css, image, hover

On my homepage in Chrome I use a html page with icons to most used websites.
I try to upgrade it from a normal table to somewhat dynamic and mor eye-pleasing.

I rounded corners and grayed the icons (when hover they become full-colour). This works
I also want to make them expand when hovering... I can't get this to work, some images are under the rest of the other.

Here's my code

```
<head>
<title>Start</title>
<style type="text/css">
body    {
    background-image: url(Greylight.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: black;
    }

table, th, td {
    border: 0px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
    padding: 6px;
    }

img     {
    border-radius: 25%;
    }

p   {
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#808080 #800080;
    } 


    div img {
    transition: all 0.2s;
    filter: grayscale(80%);
    }

div img:hover {
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    transform: scale(2);
    }

</style>
</head>
```

```
<td>
<a href="http://.."><div><img src="image.jpg" alt="test" width="80" height="80"></a></div>
</td>
```

```
<td>
<a href="http://.."><div><img src="image.jpg" alt="test" width="80" height="80"></a></div>
</td>
```

```

I know there's a line in css with absolete bu that didn't work, anyone who knows how to fix it?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the :hover on the td but to apply the modification to your img ?

```
td:hover > img {
scale(2)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input, but this didn't work also. You mean i put this line in my css between the other lines?